# Show categories and then show sub-categories in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm seem to be stuck on something..

What I'm trying to do: with the following sample data I'm trying to show the data first in category and then show the data in the subcategory.

Sample Data:

```
array('category'=> 'America',
'sub-category'=> 'Illinois',
'name'=>'John Doe');

array('category'=>'America',
'sub-category'=>'Wisconsin',
'name'=>'Jane Doe');
```

Basically like this:

```
America
  Illinois
    John Doe
  Wisconsin
    Jane Doe
```

I can do the category by using the following code:

```
   foreach ($total_states as $key => $states) {
     $states_category[$states['CATEGORY']]['category'] = $states['CATEGORY'];   
     $statest_category[$states['CATEGORY']]['name'][] = $states;    
   }
```

How can I break it down by sub-categories using that for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested and come up with this code:

```
<?php
$datas = [
    [
        'category' => 'America',
        'sub-category' => 'Illinois',
        'name' => 'John Doe'
    ],
    [
        'category' => 'America',
        'sub-category' => 'State',
        'name' => 'John Doedf'
    ],
    [
        'category' => 'America',
        'sub-category' => 'State',
        'name' => 'ghghjgj Doe'
    ],
];

$newArray = [];

foreach($datas as $d) 
    $newArray[$d['category']][$d['sub-category']][] = $d['name'];

foreach($newArray as $country => $city) {
    echo $country. '<br>';

    foreach($city as $subcity => $users) {
        echo "\t $subcity <br>";

        foreach($users as $u)
            echo "\t\t $u <br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this:

Initial data:

```
$info = [
         ['category' => 'America',
          'sub-category' => 'Illinois',
          'name' => 'John Doe'],
        ['category' => 'America',
         'sub-category' => 'Wisconsin',
         'name' => 'Jane Doe']];
```

Foreach:

```
        foreach ( $info as $array ){
            foreach ( $array as $key => $value){
                switch ( $key ){
                    case 'category' : {
                        echo $value . '<br>'; 
                        break;
                    }
                    case 'sub-category' : {
                        echo "&nbsp; " . $value . '<br>';
                        break;
                    }
                    case 'name' : {
                        echo "&nbsp; &nbsp; " . $value . '<br>';
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```